# Python combine two for loops

Tags: python

Currently I would do:

```
for x in [1,2,3]:
    for y in [1,2,3]:
        print x,y
```

Is there way of doing something like below,

```
for x,y in ([1,2,3],[1,2,3]):
    print x,y
```

Would like to shorten this kind of loop and this throws the "too many to unpack" exception.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
import itertools
for x, y in itertools.product([1,2,3], [1,2,3]):
    print x, y
```

prints all nine pairs:

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 1
3 2
3 3
```

**UPDATE**: If the two variables `x` and `y` are to be chosen from one list, you can use the `repeat` keyword (as proposed by *agf*):

```
import itertools
for x, y in itertools.product([1,2,3], repeat=2):
    print x, y
```

Comment: or `product([1, 2, 3], repeat=2)`.

Comment: @agf: thanks! I always used `product(**[1,2,3]*2)`. I might still use my method because it's more explicit, but `repeat=...` might be more readable.

Comment: @ninjagecko I assume you mean `product(*[[1,2,3]]*2)`, but I don't see that as more explicit. As you've shown, it's also easier to get wrong. Shameless self promotion: See my highly upvoted answer to [What is the best way to generate all possible three letter strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7074066/500584)

Comment: @agf: Ah yes, I meant `product(*[ [1,2,3] ]*2)`. I feel it's more explicit because `repeat=` requires the user to know about what that keyword does, but `repeat=` is pretty elegant. =) Nice answer; exactly how I'd do it.

Comment: if the length is difference in that case

Answer (score 16):

You could use a generator expression in the for loop:

```
for x, y in ((a,b) for a in [1,2,3] for b in [5,6,7]):
  print x, y
```

Comment: FWIW - please include a reference to "generator expression". Your answer was the one that helped me today. About 8 yeas later. :) Thank you!