# Python- How to find all possible combinations in an array of string

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, iterator

I have a string array such as ['abc', 'xy','d', 'mzqr']

I wounder if there is a simple solution to find all possible characters combination like:

- axdm
- aydm
- aydz
- a...
- bxdm
- ...

Thanks !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to generate all possible three letter strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074051/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-all-possible-three-letter-strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

lst = ['abc', 'xy','d', 'mzqr']

list(map(''.join, product(*lst)))
# ['axdm', 'axdz', 'axdq', 'axdr', 'aydm', 'aydz', 'aydq', 'aydr', 
#  'bxdm', 'bxdz', 'bxdq', 'bxdr', 'bydm', 'bydz', 'bydq', 'bydr', 
#  'cxdm', 'cxdz', 'cxdq', 'cxdr', 'cydm', 'cydz', 'cydq', 'cydr']
```

`product` takes any number of iterables (here your `*`-unpacked list of strings) and produces their cartesian product in the form of a lazy iterator over `tuples`. This the uses [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to turn the tuples back into strings.