# Go from aaaa to zzzz python

Tags: python, brute-force

I need to find a way to brute-force from aaaa to zzzz using python (aaaa, aaab, aaac... zzzz).
Similar to 0000 to 9999.
Is there a "magical" way to do that using loops and lists?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Have you looked into [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074051/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-all-possible-three-letter-strings)

Comment: charses = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
listilist= []
for current in xrange(10):
    a = [i for i in your_list]
    for y in xrange(current):
        a = [x+i for i in charses for x in a]
    listilist= listilist+a

Comment: is there a way to do that without itertools?

Comment: @Tahalich please updated in the question, not post in comment

Comment: @Tahalich edit the question and show what you've tried there, not in comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very "basic" example:

```
chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
my_list = []

for c1 in chars:
    for c2 in chars:
        for c3 in chars:
            for c4 in chars:
                my_list.append(c1+c2+c3+c4)
                
print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this succinctly with using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools
import string

for elem in itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=5):
    ...
```

Here's a sample for the first 30 values yielded by this approach:

```
>>> values = itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=5)
>>> print(list(itertools.islice(values, 30)))
[
    ('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'), 
    ('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b'), 
    ('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c'), 
    # --Snip -- 
    ('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'x'), 
    ('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'y'), 
    ('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'z'), 
    ('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a'), 
    ('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'), 
    ('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'), 
    ('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'd')
]
```

Note that there are `26**5 == 11881376` values in this sequence, so you probably don't want to store them all in a list. On my system, such a list it occupies roughly 100 MiB.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to know what you consider "magical", but I don't see the magic in loops.
Here is one variation:

```
cs = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
list(map(''.join, [(a,b,c,d) for a in cs for b in cs for c in cs for d in cs]))
```