# Python create all pairs of letters from abcdefghijkl... letter string

Tags: python

```
import string
letters=string.ascii_lowercase
letters

'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

we are looking to convert `letters` into a list of length 26^2, featuring all unordered pairings of letters `['aa', 'ab', 'ac', ..., 'az', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', ..., 'zz']`. I am looking to avoid code that looks like this:

```
letter_list = []
for letter1 in letters:
    for letter2 in letters:
        letter_list.append(f'{letter1}{letter2}')
```

Is there a 1 liner with nested list comprehension?

Comment: `[x + y for x in letters for y in letters]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to generate all possible three letter strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074051/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-all-possible-three-letter-strings) (Yes, it's for 3-letter strings but it's the same solution for 2-letter strings, just need to adjust the itertools param or the non-itertools loop solutions).

Comment: With https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations: `combinations('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 2)`

Answer (score -5):

A nested loop is probably the right way...Sorry about that

Try:

```
letter_list = []
letters = 'abcdefg...'
letters = list(letters)
for x in letters:
    for y in letters:
         letter_list.append(x+y)
```

Sorry that it is a nested loop. I don't think that making it a single line will be very easy, and probably won't be worth it, because users don't usually look at the back-end. Good luck!

-Codeitfast

Comment: How is this an answer?  It's exactly what the questioner said they _didn't_ want.

Comment: Perhaps, but it shouldn't matter too much. You should try to have code that's easier for the humans, not the computers.