# Get all possible character pair of a string in python

Tags: python-3.x

How do I get all possible character pairs of a string using python. Each character should also pair with itself. For example taking the string 'abc' the output should be:

'aa'
'bb'
'cc'
'ab'
'ac'
'ba'
'bc'
'ca'
'cb'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to generate all possible three letter strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074051/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-all-possible-three-letter-strings)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) here

Like this :

```py
import itertools

s = "abc"
print(" ".join(map(lambda x: "".join(x), itertools.product(s, repeat=2))))
```

Which would result in :

```
aa ab ac ba bb bc ca cb cc
```

Comment: Code-only questions are not very useful, especially for beginner questions like this one. I suggest you break down your convoluted one-liner into understandable parts and add some textual explanation.